# Protect deletion of category, when something is associated with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rubygems, observer-pattern, destroy

Category has many products, videos, music etc.

When category in question will be destroyed, all stuff, associated with it, will be broken.

Sure, I can manually implement #before_destroy method of ActiveRecord, but, this is not good solution, i think.

Is there any Rails gem, that checks declared association of models with Category and prevent deletion, if something is associated with it?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality comes standard with rails.

Use :dependent => :restrict when declaring your association.

See the doc here for more:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: the question is how to prevent deletion not how to cascade it.

Comment: ah... just re-read it and yes, you are right. I got confused. Well, there's something for that too, with dependent => :restrict

Comment: this is why i love SO - learn something new every day! Good call!

Answer (score 1):

Option
`:dependent => :restrict`
does exactly this.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure it never happens (and you should!), add a database constraint. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html or http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-constraints.html